# Deploying a Reactjs application (CRA) on heroku throws an error

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app, craco

Following is the error I am getting. The front-end of the application is built using CRA. And the backend is built with Laravel - Laravel Sanctum and Laravel Fortify. I am using craco for building the app.

Error: React Refresh runtime should not be included in the production bundle.

Comment: Is react-refresh installed as a dependency instead of a devDependency?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Heroku was building the react app using nodejs buildpack. In order to deploy a react project scaffolded using create-react-app a buildpack other than "heroku/nodejs" needs to be used. In my case I used this buildpack -> https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git. And finally using this I got the app to working.

Thank you @mando for you help.